# Ctrl+Shift+B, subdivides bevel instead of smoothing bevel. How do I smooth it?

Tags: modeling, vertices, bevel

This is my current mesh:

[image]

I want to turn the square hole into this shape:

[image]

I tried <kbd>⎈ CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to **bevel** the *vertices*, and it gave me this:

[image]

But the problem is when I scrolled up, instead of giving me a smooth circle-like bevel, it simply subdivided the diamond:

[image]

How can I create the circle-like shape I desire here?

Comment: There are 18 blades try to make single blade and then array and rotate it

Comment: I don't know what you men by that @ateks?

Comment: i want to say that there are 18 side so make 1 side then rotate

Comment: @Accumulator are you gonna use Subsurf Modifier for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll present you method based purely on quad topology.

[image: Final]

It's a little bit manual work, but nothing is worth more then nice quad base topology.

Make sure you have enabled **F2** addon in **User Preferences** as it will speed up last step. You certainly don't need it. It will be just easier.

[image: Final]

1. Delete 3 bottom vertices.
2. Add a **Circle** and set **Vertices** to **8/12/16/20/24**... and so on. Just to have straight horizontal vertices along **Circle**. I have used 16 in this example.
3. Scale it down approximately between existing shape then scale it up with **Vertex Snap** and hover closest vertex. I've done it holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while scaling.
4. Remove top part of the **Circle**.
5. <kbd>W</kbd> > **Remove Doubles** to "merge" **Circle** with existing shape.
6. Select 2 vertices on one chosen side right before empty face, move mouse cursor to the other side and hold <kbd>F</kbd> (**F2** addon).

I have two other methods on my mind but this seems to be the cleanest one so far.

Answer (score 1):

I rather like @LukeD's answer, but I started writing this last night, and I like that it starts from where @Accumulator left off:

I'm no expert with the bevel tool, so this might not qualify as the answer to your original question, but the question I saw at the end was how to produce the desired shape. That I think I have a good answer:

For reference, I've labeled the points in your last screenshot:
[image: All labeled vertices]

1. Select and delete vertex A and vertex D.
2. Select vertices L and R, and snap the 3D cursor to the selection, so it should jump to C.
3. Select vertices L and B, duplicate them with [Shift]+[D], and rotate them 45 degrees around the 3D cursor.
4. Add vertices L and B to the selection, duplicate them with [Shift]+[D], and rotate them 22.5 degrees around the 3D cursor.
5. Steps 3 & 4 gave you 6 new points. These are where we will move points E, F, G, J, K and M to using this procedure 6 times:

   A. Select the new vertex location.

   B. Add the original vertex to the selection.

   C. Merge the vertices to the first point.
6. (Optional) move vertex H and vertex N  slightly closer to C, to ensure all quads are properly convex.

This diagram should give an idea what the final quads would look like:

[image: final mesh topology (on left side)]

I've been away from blender for a few weeks, so feel free to add any hotkeys I may have forgotten. I hope you find this helpful.